# Why program leaves loop on one computer and not on the other?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I made a simple loop on my computer and it works perfectly. I wrote the same program on my laptop (both Visual Studio 2017) but instead of repeating, after one execution of the loop it leaves.

I also noticed that when I set release configuration (instead of debug) program works just fine.

Can somebody tell me what should I do to repair this?

Entire Program:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    while(char x = _getch())
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: conio.h, where does this come from? `_getch` is not a standard function as well.

Comment: What's in `"pch.h"` ?

Comment: @SidS precompiled header.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, D'Oh!

Comment: I believe if you hit a special key like an arrow key, `_getch()` can return 0 and then the next call will return which special key was hit. Maybe you hit an arrow key by mistake?

Comment: *Does somebody can tell me what should I do to repair this?* -- The code is doing exactly as you wrote.  What is there to repair?  The loop exits if [getch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2017) returns a 0.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2017) of _getch()  :

> When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code.

This explains why your code is exiting the loop after one iteration.